# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters

Tags: java, appium

I'm getting an error when using the following code:

```
driver.findElementByClassName("//android.widget.EditText").sendKeys("hello");
```

Here is the whole code:

```
package aaaaa;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

public class basics extends base {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']").click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='3. Preference dependencies']").click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.CheckBox").click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='WiFi settings']").click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElementByClassName("//android.widget.EditText").click();
        Thread.sleep(30000);
        driver.findElementById("//android:id/edit").sendKeys("hi");
        driver.findElementByClassName("//android.widget.EditText").sendKeys("hello");
    }
}
```

I expect text to be entered in `EditText`.

Comment: Please add the html of the element on which the exception is coming

Comment: HI sameer i'm new to stackover flow. i dont know how to post a questions and follow the steps.

Comment: i am sharing screenshots for Uiautomator its as follows:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yYyOklO2hF75KIdg66W8gQbuJOi2OWH1

Comment: No issues, please but the html of the element in the question itself

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the element is not getting found is that you have used `//` it in the `className` hjust like you are using it in the xpath.
However while finding any element using tags like `className` or `id`, `//` are not required.

You can find the element by using `className` like:

```
driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText").click();
```

And as the id is also present for the element, you can find the element by using id as well, like:

```
 driver.findElementById("android:id/edit").sendKeys("hello");
```

Comment: While this probably works, I think it wise to add for the original poster that the reason the original code won't work is because it was attempting to lookup by classname, but the passed parameter started with double slashes - like an xpath.

Comment: @BillHileman yup right, i am updating my answer as per your suggestion